# SQL Server 2008: Pivot column with no aggregate function workaround

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, pivot

Yes I know, this question has been asked MANY times but after reading all the posts I found that there wasn't an answer that fits my need. So, Heres my question. I would like to take a column of values and pivot them into rows of 6 columns.

```
I want to take this......    And turn it into this.......................
G                            Letter  Date    Code  Ammount   Name       Account 
081278                       G       081278   12   00123535  John Doe   123456
12
00123535
John Doe
123456
```

I have 110000 values in this one column in one table called TempTable. I need all the values displayed because each row is an entity to itself. For instance, There is one unique entry for all of the Letter, Date, Code, Ammount, Name, and Account columns. I understand that the aggregate function is required but is there a workaround that will allow me to get this desired result?

Comment: What is the key to pivot the 6 rows into 6 columns? AKA, what is the key that associates them?

Comment: There is no association. Thats kind of my problem each set of values are unique. The only thing that deliniates them is that there are six values an empty value and then six more and so on. This table will be used as read only and is not tied to any other table as in PK, FK, etc.

Comment: Would it be possible to use a auto num column like a surragate key and then just sum the keys. I could drop them after. I just can't group the values because I need to see them all, they are all unique.

Comment: @2boolORNOT2bool: so you don't care what row goes into what column? And you don't care if G goes with Jo Blow and H goes with John Doe, say (your example has G and John Doe)? Or don't care if Jo Blow goes into the Letter column and G into the Date column?

Comment: Well yes but thats the only thing that I need. I thought you were refering to grouping as in, if there are three John Doe's combind the information and list in one row. Sorry if I was confuseing and I do appreciate the help.

Comment: The column rows are also fixed as in there will be 110000 rows in the table every time I run the script to generate the table. I dont know if this will help or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a MAX aggregate

If one row = one column (per group of 6 rows) then MAX of a single value = that row value.

However, the data you've posted in insufficient. I don't see anything to:

- associate the 6 rows per group
- distinguish whether a row is "Letter" or "Name"

There is no implicit row order or number to rely upon to generate the groups

Comment: The grouping is the mind boggle. In this case I don't want to group I just want to flip the data into a row set split into columns. Is this even possible?

Comment: Also @gbn, you actually helped me get to this point by answering http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5955227/sql-server-2008-t-sql-udf-odds-and-ends which I truely appreciate but if its easier to edit the split UDF to display the results in the form I described here I would be glad to go back to the drawing board and redo my code. But I wouldnt know how...

Comment: I think I will try to generate a column that numbers each value set like for the fist row if could just have 1,1,1,1,1,1 in the table next to the values and group by those numbers. I hope I havn't pissed you off. You have been very helpful today and in the past. Thanks!

Comment: Max did work, and I used the ordinal number from the script for column headers. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the max columns in a SQL 2008 select statement is 4,096 as per [MSDN Max Capacity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).

Instead of using a pivot, you might consider dynamic SQL to get what you want to do.

```
Declare @SQLColumns nvarchar(max),@SQL nvarchar(max)
select @SQLColumns=(select '''+ColName+'''',' from TableName for XML Path(''))
set @SQLColumns=left(@SQLColumns,len(@SQLColumns)-1)

set @SQL='Select '+@SQLColumns
exec sp_ExecuteSQL @SQL,N''
```

Comment: Well I actually only need 6 columns the table that I want to pivot just has a single column with around 110000 values.